# How can I add automatic click functionality after 60second to button and perform that operation using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried solutions for similar asked questions before but they are not working for my purpose
This is my button

```
 <a class="goto-next-slide overlay-button overlay-right" id="nxt">Next</a>
```

this is my javascrit function which is performing click operation

```
function gotoNextSlide() {
goToSlide(getCurrentSlide().index() + 1);
 }
```

Now the event is happening only when I clicked the button but what should I do to perform  operation  when next button get clicked automatically after 60 seconds.
this is my jquery where I am calling the  `gotoNextSlide()` function.

```
function init() {
$("#nxt").click(gotoNextSlide);
}
$(document).ready(init);
```

how can I do it?

I tried by  this method

```
<script>
    var tmp;
    function f1() {
        tmp = setTimeout("(gotoNextSlide)", 2000);
    }
    function callNext() {
        document.getElementById("nxt").click();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried a `setTimeout` yet?

Comment: yes but still  its not chnaging .

Comment: Please post what you've tried with `setTimeout`.

Comment: So you don't actually want the button to be clicked, but you want the next slide to be shown?

Comment: Change to `setTimeout(gotoNextSlide, 2000);` if you want it every 60 seconds, then `setInterval(gotoNextSlide, 60000);`

Comment: yes  you got it  and I posted my tried code in above post , please check that  and guide me where I went wrong?

Comment: hey thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setTimeout to queue goToNextSlide after 60 seconds. Whenever someone clicks "next" button or 60 seconds passed, clear the timeout, change the slide, and queue it again after 60 seconds.

```
var timer;

function gotoNextSlide() {
   timer && clearTimeout(timer);
   goToSlide(getCurrentSlide().index() + 1);
   timer = setTimeout(gotoNextSlide, 1000 * 60);
}

function init() {
  $("#nxt").click(gotoNextSlide);
  timer = setTimeout(gotoNextSlide, 1000 * 60);
}
$(document).ready(init);
```